# Making a high score (best time) localStorage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around using a localStorage for a high score. I have saved the variable for the high score but now getting it to refresh with a new high score has become the issue.

So I have reverted back to the start and I have just these lines:

```
localStorage.setItem('score', timeDiff.toFixed(3));
parseFloat(document.getElementById("best_score").innerHTML = "My best time is " + localStorage.getItem('score') + " s");
```

My plan is then, if that user scores a better time than all their other attempts, this is saved as their best time.

I realise I need to do an "if" statement. So, the best I can come up with at the moment is human speak not JavaScript.

If score is nothing, then just print the new score.

If the score is better than the current printed score, then print that one instead.

If the score isn't as good as the current score, then don't do anything at all.

And that is it!

Be grateful for anyone to push me in the right direction of how to write those if statements.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're having problems with when trying to translate the "human-speak" into JavaScript? It seems pretty straight forward and somebody on here just translating it for you seems less useful than helping you translating it on your own.

Comment: First get the last saved high score and check if it is set. Then get the current score after the user has done something. Now make your if statements. Your flow is quite alright, if you ask me. Make an attempt and we'll help you out from there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Here's the [MDN page on `if`/`else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). In general, MDN is markedly higher quality than w3schools.

Comment: using if or else statements isn't my problem - I can do that. The issue I have is what variables do I need to put into this.

Comment: For instance, I have set "score" as the timeDiff which is the current game output. This is fine. But when I play the game again, all I am doing is updating "score" and not storing it anywhere. My question is how do I get "score" to be stored so I can assess if the new game is better or worse (or the same) as the last game or any game they played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for the `parseFloat` in your example, but you will probably want `parseFloat` as part of this solution.

The update would look something like this:

```
// Get the previous high score if any, or `NaN` if none
// `localStorage.score` will be `undefined` if you've never stored a high score
// at all (or a string otherwise). `parseFloat` will return `NaN` if you pass it
// `undefined`, so we check that later.
const lastHighScore = parseFloat(localStorage.score);
// Get the string version of this score
const scoreString = timeDiff.toFixed(3);
let message;
if (isNaN(lastHighScore) || timeDiff > lastHighScore) { // ** Perhaps < ? Hard to tell from the question
    // New high score
    message = "Your new best time is " + scoreString;
    // Store the new score
    localStorage.score = scoreString;
} else {
    // Not a new high score
    message = "Your time was " + scoreString + "; your best time was " + localStorage.score;
}
document.getElementById("best_score").textContent = message;
```

Given the starting point seems to have a value in `timeDiff`, I couldn't see how a score could be "nothing."

(If you want to use `getItem()` and `setItem()` instead, note that `getItem()` will return `null` [not `undefined`] if the item doesn't exist. But `parseFloat(null)` also gives you `NaN`, so...)

Comment: `localStorage.score === null` is most likely wrong as the default for it will be `undefined` change it to `localStorage.score == null` or `localStorage.score === undefined`
@OP: see Equality operators on the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators to see the difference

Comment: @SourceOverflow - Gah, thanks. I vacillated between using the property access and using `getItem`. The latter returns `null` for items that don't exist. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you... this does work. And it does sort out the issues I had. It's much more complex than I had done in the first place - so for a beginner this was tough. But your commenting in there is amazing. 

And yes, it was < :) but that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, based on what you wrote in the comment, your problem is not actually the `if` statements, but how to structure it so it gets updated properly.

The answer to this is creating a function that does all of this for you.
Let's call it `updateHighscore`.
This function will take a new score, then see if it's a high score and if it is, update everything accordingly.
Whenever a game is finished now, you just call this method.

E.g. See the following:

```
function updateHighscore(newScore) {
  // get current highscore
  const oldHighscore = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('score'))

  if (oldHighscore == null // if it doesn't exist yet
      || oldHighscore < newScore) { // or if it's smaller than the new score (I assume bigger means better here)
    // current highscore needs to be updated
    localStorage.setItem('score', newScore)
    // html needs to be updated
    document.getElementById("best_score").innerHTML = "My best time is " + localStorage.getItem('score') + " s"
  }
}
```

Now, whenever the game is finished and you have a new score, just call this method with the score and it should update everything accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this when user gets a new highscore:

```
localStorage.setItem('score', timeDiff.toFixed(3));

document.getElementById("best_score").innerHTML = "My best time is " + parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('score')) + " s";
```

to check the highscore, do like this:

```
var highScore = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('score'));
    
highScore = highScore > currentScore ? highScore : currentScore;

localStorage.setItem('score', highScore);
```

Comment: I vote up the ternary operator, its much cleaner than a traditional if else if

Comment: I don't think this is the answer he wants to have. He's having trouble to translate english into JavaScript. As such any good answer should at least extensively explain what it does. He's probably just starting out.
@Zachucks I actually find the ternary operator making it more complicated that it needs to be. Don't get me wrong, I love it and use it regularily, but just adding it to a code snippet that is targeted at a beginner without explaining it, probably does really complicate his understanding.

Comment: Is the "hightScore" a deliberate spelling mistake? I assume so, it is in there several times. 

I copied and pasted this, but it didn't work and I am quite unsure about the use of currentScore and hightScore.

Comment: @PaulDavis Yes, it was a spelling mistake, sorry for inconvenience, here i am checking current score with the saved high score, if current score is greater than saved high score then current score will be new high score that's it.